# Caffe import error. possible pycaffe was not make?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, caffe, pycaffe

can anyone help with this issue. 
I am a beginner currently running on Ubuntu 14.04, python 3.4.3. CUDA 7.5 and opencv3 is installed.

I am trying out the demo.py of py-faster-rcnn. I have caffe installation up to the point `sudo make run test` with success following the installation from http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation

When i run sudo make pycaffe. I was promted with this

```
touch python/caffe/proto/__init__.py
PROTOC (python) src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
```

i did not look into the situation much and carry on with the process. i assumed the entire caffe installation was done. I opened up a new terminal `cd python3` and `import caffe` with success

And now i tried to run the demo.py to give a try and saw this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 18, in <module>
    from fast_rcnn.test import im_detect
  File "/home/galvan/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    import caffe
  File "/home/galvan/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver
  File "/home/galvan/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /home/galvan/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../caffe-fast-rcnn/python/caffe/../../build/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8imencodeERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayERSt6vectorIhSaIhEERKS6_IiSaIiEE
```

this is make Makefile.config

```
    ## Refer to http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html
# Contributions simplifying and improving our build system are welcome!

# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
# CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
# USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# uncomment to allow MDB_NOLOCK when reading LMDB files (only if necessary)
#   You should not set this flag if you will be reading LMDBs with any
#   possibility of simultaneous read and write
# ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK := 1

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# To customize your choice of compiler, uncomment and set the following.
# N.B. the default for Linux is g++ and the default for OSX is clang++
# CUSTOM_CXX := g++

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 through *_61 lines for compatibility.
# For CUDA < 8.0, comment the *_60 and *_61 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
#       -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
#       -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
#       -gencode arch=compute_61,code=compute_61

# BLAS choice:
# atlas for ATLAS (default)
# mkl for MKL
# open for OpenBlas
BLAS := atlas
# Custom (MKL/ATLAS/OpenBLAS) include and lib directories.
# Leave commented to accept the defaults for your choice of BLAS
# (which should work)!
# BLAS_INCLUDE := /path/to/your/blas
# BLAS_LIB := /path/to/your/blas

# Homebrew puts openblas in a directory that is not on the standard search path
# BLAS_INCLUDE := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/include
# BLAS_LIB := $(shell brew --prefix openblas)/lib

# This is required only if you will compile the matlab interface.
# MATLAB directory should contain the mex binary in /bin.
# MATLAB_DIR := /usr/local
# MATLAB_DIR := /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app

# NOTE: this is required only if you will compile the python interface.
# We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.
PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
        /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
# Anaconda Python distribution is quite popular. Include path:
# Verify anaconda location, sometimes it's in root.
# ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/include/python2.7 \
        # $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include

# Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

# We need to be able to find libpythonX.X.so or .dylib.
PYTHON_LIB := /usr/lib
# PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib

# Homebrew installs numpy in a non standard path (keg only)
# PYTHON_INCLUDE += $(dir $(shell python -c 'import numpy.core; print(numpy.core.__file__)'))/include
# PYTHON_LIB += $(shell brew --prefix numpy)/lib

# Uncomment to support layers written in Python (will link against Python libs)
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# NCCL acceleration switch (uncomment to build with NCCL)
# https://github.com/NVIDIA/nccl (last tested version: v1.2.3-1+cuda8.0)
# USE_NCCL := 1

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

# N.B. both build and distribute dirs are cleared on `make clean`
BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

# Uncomment for debugging. Does not work on OSX due to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/171
# DEBUG := 1

# The ID of the GPU that 'make runtest' will use to run unit tests.
TEST_GPUID := 0

# enable pretty build (comment to see full commands)
Q ?= @
```

May I know why am I getting this error? pls provide step by step solution. Beginner here. Thanks!

Comment: looks like error is with opencv linking. Add opencv shared object path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: how do i solve it?

Comment: add this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pathtoopencvlib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to ~/.bashrc file. then do `source .bashrc`. Now open a new terminal and run your code.

Comment: im sorry but what command to enter to invoke ~/.bashrc file?

Comment: In a terminal do this `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`. it will open the file in the editor. Then add the above line at the end of the file. Instead of `pathtoopencvlib` use your opencv lib path. Also you should familiarize yourself to ubuntu first.

Comment: thanks @lnman i will give a try. I took up this project to fulfil my degree. its painful that the learning curve is so steep.